# getLastKnownLocation return NULL

Tags: android

I'm using GPS. This is my code.

```
   public void onCreate() 
{
    super.onCreate();

    mLocationManager  = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location mLocation;

    if(mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled((LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)))
    {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER , 2000, 10, myLocationListener);
        mLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Temp = updateWithNewLocation(mLocation);
        Value.city = Temp;  
        Temp = "";
        LogShow("DataClass.City = " + Value.city);
        LogShow("GPS_PROVIDER enable");
    }
  }
```

I don't know why getLastKnownLocation return NULL. So updateWithNewLocation will be empty.
I use a permission ACCESS FINE LOCATION.

How can I solve it?

Comment: `getLastKnownLocation()` will return null if it believes the location is too outdated

Comment: getLastKnownLocation() could be out-of-date as @raghav said , for example if the device was turned off and moved to another location.You should grab the new location by requesting new location update..  Also I would suggest to consider your accuracy and battery constraint so as to either go on with NETWORK_PROVIDER rather than GPS_PROVIDER

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getLastKnownLocation, try requestLocationUpdates. You can use a LocationListener to listen for location updates. More info:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html

[Refrence Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894195/getting-android-location-and-return-unknown-or-null-when-providers-are-unavail)

Comment: OK. I use a Location Listener and update using getFromLocaion.

Answer (score 0):

try this.....

```
   mGoogleMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick()
                        {

                            Location myLocation = mGoogleMap.getMyLocation();
                            onLocationChanged(myLocation);
                            return false;
                        }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem. Your code is OK.  The problem is that gps does't get signal when you're indoors and getLastKnownLocation method with gps provider will return null.  when you go outdoors, you code should work correctly.